# Can't set SelectionKey 's interestOps in separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I'm trying to make a simple server using NIO with selectable channels and to move all "heavy" logic outside the main NIO loop into a separate thread. But I can't register SelectionKey from other thread. Sorry for the long read.

Server in started as usual:

```
ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
Selector selector;
try {
   serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
   ServerSocket ss = serverChannel.socket();
   InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(port);
   ss.bind(address);
   serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
   selector = Selector.open();
   serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
} catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   return;
}
```

Then goes the main loop where on accept stage (key.isAcceptable()) I perform accept (I'd prefer to accept a connection in a separate thread, but it seems that without accept in main NIO loop I will not get SocketChannel object):

```
ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
SocketChannel sChann = server.accept();
```

and then I pass current SocketChannel and SelectionKey to the 2nd thread in order to make some checks and decide if channel should be closed or I can read the data from the channel. If all checks are successfully passed I'm trying to register OP_READ flag for this key and get the following problems:

It's written in Java manual, that `SelectionKey` is constant for the channel. However, when in 2nd thread I'm trying to perform

```
key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:98)
    at ConnectionAcceptor.run(ConnectionAcceptor.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I've read about this exception in manual

> IllegalArgumentException - If a bit in the set does not correspond to
>   an operation that is supported by this key's channel, that is, if (ops
>   & ~channel().validOps()) != 0

and added some ckecks to see if it's my case. The checks in 2nd thread are:

```
System.out.println("ConnectionAcceptor: valid options " + ci.sockChan.validOps());
System.out.println("ConnectionAcceptor: OP_ACCEPT " + SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
System.out.println("ConnectionAcceptor: OP_READ " + SelectionKey.OP_READ);
System.out.println("ConnectionAcceptor: OP_WRITE " + SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

result is:

```
ConnectionAcceptor: valid options 13
ConnectionAcceptor: OP_ACCEPT 16
ConnectionAcceptor: OP_READ 1
ConnectionAcceptor: OP_WRITE 4
```

so, the rule from manual is not violated and IllegalArgumentException should not be raised.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810087/interestops-throws-illegalargumentexception) I've found another method to set required flag:

```
sockChan.keyFor(selector).interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

but using it in my 2nd thread I get

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConnectionAcceptor.run(ConnectionAcceptor.java:59)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

As a result, it looks like while channel and key objects were transferred to 2nd thread, the main NIO loop maid some iterations and channel's SelectionKey became not valid.
Please, help me to find the way of registering channel's selector flag from 2nd thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

you're trying to change the interest set of the registration from

```
/* SelectionKey key = */ serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

That `ServerSocketChannel` only supports `OP_ACCEPT`.

What you want to do is register a new `OP_READ` on the newly accepted socket channel

```
SelectionKey aNewKey = sChann.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

That new key will drive the operations on that socket.

---

Your second attempt failed because your `SocketChannel` wasn't registered for any `Selector` and therefore `keyFor` returned `null`.

Comment: Hi, Savior! Thank you for quick response, but could you please explain a little bit more: I pass to the 2nd thread SocketChannel, not ServerSocketChannel and I pass there a key obtained from selector.selectedKeys().iterator(). When I use this key in main NIO loop, everything works fine and I can change the interest set. However, using the SAME key object in 2nd thread raises an error.

Comment: @DolgalevDenis The `SelectionKey` in your example is the key used to register the server socket. It can only represent "accept" operations, because that's all a server socket does. You need a new key for the connected socket, where you can read and write, that's why you need to register the connected socket with the selector.

Comment: I've got this and sChann.register(...) works well in 2nd thread. Thank you for this. But  also I'm trying to understand why key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ) works well in 1st thread (with main NIO loop) if, as I understood you, it's a key that registered ServerSocketChannel?

Comment: @DolgalevDenis That definitely should not work, regardless of thread. If you print `serverChannel.validOps()`, it'll only print 16, which is `OP_ACCEPT`.

Comment: Savior, you were right. I had try/catch block without logging. Added logging showed the same exception. Thank you.